# Generating GraphQL GUI from Schema and Schema from GUI

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, express-graphql

While using GraphiQL works well, my boss has asked me to implement a user interface where users can check elements presented to them via UI elements like checkbox, map relationships and get the data and doing this will generate a graphql input for the person, call the API and get the result back to the user.

So, basically this involves 2 generations. Generating a user interface from a GraphQL schema and generating a GraphQL input query from the user's selection.

I searched and I was not able to find any tools which already do this. My server is in Node and I am using Express GraphQL. I converted my express schema to GraphQLSchema language using https://github.com/graphql-cli/graphql-cli and I introspected the GraphQLSchema language using the introspect function at https://github.com/sheerun/graphqlviz/blob/master/cli.js

The object which I got was something like this (only partial schema output given below)
`

```
"data": {
        "__schema": {
            "queryType": {
                "name": "Query"
            },
            "mutationType": {
                "name": "Mutation"
            },
            "subscriptionType": null,
            "types": [{
                "kind": "OBJECT",
                "name": "Query",
                "description": null,
                "fields": [{
                    "name": "employee",
                    "description": null,
                    "args": [{
                        "name": "ecode",
                        "description": null,
                        "type": {
                            "kind": "SCALAR",
                            "name": "String",
                            "ofType": null
                        },
                        "defaultValue": null
                    }],
```

`

I am looping through the elements trying to generate UI but I am quite stuck.

What is the best way to do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Well for the part of generating the ui from the introspection query, I think that the response contains enough data for a sufficient ui (description for each field can be used as a placeholder for each field's input box). If you're asking how can you generate a dynamic form from the introspection response, you can take a look at other projects that created transformers from json to html forms for inspiration/usage (take a look at https://github.com/brutusin/json-forms/blob/master/README.md#cdn). For complex fields  (not primitive types) you may need to do some more work.

For the schema generation from the ui, you can use any query builder tool, and build a query according to the user inputs. Each combobox will be mapped to a specific SCHEMANAME.FIELDNAME and the value will be the value of the input box.

I hope it helped a bit. BTW, it sounds like an interesting tool so let us know if you succeed!